# Using TextFormField in Stateless widget is very difficult in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use TextFormField in a stateless widget along with ScopedModel to deal with text in it and facing various issues as follow.

1. I tried using controller for field, but everytime I enter some text and press done on keyboard, text gets cleared. No idea as to why.
2. If I remove controller, text stays in field but new problem gets created as to how to get text from field. I solved it by using callback *onFieldSubmitted*.
3. But turns out, *onFieldSubmitted* is only getting called when we click on done button on keyboard. If I enter text in field and instead of clicking ok, click on another field, callback won't get called and I will have no way of tracking what user has entered in field.

Any solution for this?

Attaching sample code for issue.

```
  class LoginPageStateless extends StatelessWidget {

  final loginUsernameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body: ScopedModelDescendant<AccountModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {
          return Form(
            //key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email id',
                    hintText: 'johndoe@ipropal.com',
                  ),
                  controller: loginUsernameController,
                  onFieldSubmitted: model.updateLoginUsernameText,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                  ),
                  controller: loginUsernameController,
                  onFieldSubmitted: model.updateLoginUsernameText,
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 39):

You cannot and should not use `Stateless` widget for storing long-term variable.

The problem is, it's exactly what you are trying to. `TextEditingController` is a class instance that should be kept between renders. But by storing it into a `StatelessWidget` you basically recreate it after every update.

You should instead convert your widget to `Stateful`. And move that controller into the `State` part

Comment: What if I move the controller into scoped model?

Comment: It should work too. Though that doesn't necessarily makes sense

Comment: But does it make sense to use scoped model with stateful widget?

Comment: Or shall I altogether drop the idea of scoped model when working with formfields?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with mixing `Stateful` widgets and scoped model. Animations and controllers are a good fit for stateful widgets.

Comment: All right, let me try it out. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: It makes more sense to use the controller in the stateful widget because that's it intended purpose. To hold state for that particular widget. If you're not using this controller outside of the widget, you don't need to put it in your ScopedModel, because scopedModel is generally for sharing variables.

Comment: @RémiRousselet, even using Provider I must use a StatefullWidget in order to have a Form ?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used a `TextFormField` till now, I always use `TextField()` for it's simplicity and flexibility. I encountered similar problem when using `Redux` and stateless widgets as I have a single source of truth at the top level store. So, I had to create some callbacks inside a `ViewModel` then assign that callback to the text field callback `onChanged` which takes in a string param.

```
CustomTextWidgetWrapper(
    onChangedCallback: viewModel.onChanged
),
```

In the `TextField` wrapped in the widget I do (not giving more details):

```
new TextField(
    controller: myController, // no use practically now
    onChanged: onChangedCallback,
```

And in the view model I get the string and dispatch to the central storage for reuse in other widget, like a button which takes the data and sends to server

```
static ViewModel fromStore(Store<AppState> store) {
    return new ViewModel(
        onChanged: (String textFieldText) {
            // I call dispatch or an API here if I want
            store.dispatch(new CallAPI(params: textFieldText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Stateless widget for storing long-term variable.

Let's assume that you have a basic behavior like when the user tap anywhere the keyboard will close , in a stateless widget that would be impossible as every time the keyboard open or close it will rebuild and creates a new instance of your text controllers ,

so in this case using a stateful widget is a must and putting your controllers in the state class

Answer (score 0):

changes textEditingController declaration as static:

```
static final loginUsernameController = TextEditingController();
```

Comment: This is not a good solution since visiting that specific screen again will not clear the text of last session.