# Is it okay to use TextEditingController in StatelessWidget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I don't need to do many things with TextEditingController but want to show the initial text. And I feel like creating StatefulWidget is too much for that.
Here's what I want my code looks like

```
// In StatelessWidget
TextField(
    controller: TextEditingController(),
)
```

But every tutorials and blog posts I've seen use TextEditingController in StatefulWidget and dispose them in the dispose method. But I can't dispose them if I use like the above

Comment: Using stateless widget you can incur in memory leak problem. Also the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) tell you to dispose the controller. Anyway there also already opened issues about this as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980118/using-textformfield-in-stateless-widget-is-very-difficult-in-flutter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using TextFormField in Stateless widget is very difficult in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980118/using-textformfield-in-stateless-widget-is-very-difficult-in-flutter)

Comment: You could dispose It If you pass It from constructor, and dispose It from parent, but I'm confused why not just use `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: @E.Benedos what memory leaks if Dart is garbage collected? There's really nothing in dispose() method except few assertions, so what are you all talking about?

Comment: @doc GC on managed languages (like DART, C#, ecc..) generally works if a resource is not used anymore. So if a resource is not disposed it cannot be cleaned by GC so it cause a memory leak. Anyway, have you read the Flutter documentation about TextEditingController?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use `TextEditingController`, there is no way around except to use a `StatefulWidget` if you want to avoid memory leaks.

However, if you see alot of boilerplate in this approach, you can use `HookWidget` ([flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks#-readme-tab-)) which gives you access to `TextEditingController` in a simple way and disposes it for you,here is a comparison:

**using `StatefulWidget`**:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController controller;
  FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: focusNode,
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController();
    focusNode = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**using `HookWidget`**:

```
class Test extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final focusNode = useFocusNode();
    final controller = useTextEditingController();
      return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: focusNode,
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What memory leaks if Dart is garbage collected? And dispose method really does nothing except few assertions...

Comment: @doc It is from the official documentation at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html :

"Remember to dispose of the TextEditingController when it is no longer needed. This will ensure we discard any resources used by the object.".  If you see that "memory leaks" is not the proper term to describe "resources used by the object" then tell me so I edit the answer with the proper term

Comment: But what resources? What resources TextEditingController is using? Are you aware of the fact that its `dispose()` method is empty?

Comment: @doc you are right that it is empty (only contains assertions), but anyway your question should be asked to the flutter team who wrote the documentation as I was only referring to them in my answer.

Comment: @doc Isn't it because the TextEditingController can have listeners? As far as I know, the listeners aren't disposed by the garbage collecter.