# Assign value of TextEditingController inside buildMethod

Tags: flutter

i have some questions about which is the correct way of creating TexEditingController;

Assuming that i want to create a controller with a fixed text, so i can do like this :

```
TextEditingController bioEditorController = new TextEditingController(text:"dummy");
```

Now  my questions is this:

if i'm usign a stateful widget i can create this controller ad assign an initial text by doing this :

```
TextEditingController bioEditorController;

@override
void initState() {
  bioEditorController = new TextEditingController(text: "dummy");
  super.initState();
}
```

but if i'm not using a stateful widget is it correct to make something like this :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 TextEditingController bioEditorController =
    new TextEditingController(text: controller.profile.value.bio);
```

What i mean is it correct to create this controller inside the build method, if i do like this it works , but i think that probably is not the best way of doing this things, also becauze i know that controller should also disposed....

I really need some help about clarifying this. Thanks

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61426096/5028715

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that doing that in the build method is not ideal. You have way less control over how many times the build method runs vs `initState`.

And while it's generally true that you would need a stateful widget when dealing with TextEditingControllers (or [hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks#-readme-tab-)), if you use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) state management it's absolutely fine, and preferred to not bother with a stateful widget just because you need a `TextEditingController`.

Another benefit of this way is very easy access to the value of the `TextEditingController` from anywhere else in the app.

Here's a quick example. This is a class where you can keep all your `TextEditingControllers`.

```
class TextController extends GetxController {
  RxString textfieldString = ''.obs; // observable String

  TextEditingController textController;

// this onInit replaces initState of a stateful widget
  @override
  onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    textController = TextEditingController(text: 'dummy');

// adding a listener that automatically updates the textfieldString with the textfield value

    textController.addListener(() {
      textfieldString.value = textController.text;
      debugPrint(textfieldString.value);
    });
  }
}
```

Initialize the controller in your main or anytime before you actually use it. This is when the `onInit` from that class is called.

```
Get.put(TextController()).textController;
```

Here's `Page1` a stateless widget with an already initialized `TextEditingController`

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<TextController>(); // finding same initialized controller
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: controller.textController, // using TextEditingConroller from GetX class
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's a quick example of a text widget on a different page automatically updating anytime the user types into the `TextFormField`

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller =
        Get.find<TextController>(); // finding same instance of controller
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        // this Obx widget rebuilds based on any updates
        child: Obx(
          () => Text(controller.textfieldString.value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So no matter where you are in your app, you can access the value of that `TextFormField` and you don't have to use a stateful widget. The `GetxController` will be removed from memory when not in use.

At this point the only time I ever need to use a stateful widget is when I need the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.

Even animations can be done with stateless widgets in GetX by adding `SingleGetTickerProviderMixin` to a Getx class and doing everything there that would normally clutter up your stateful widget.