# Whats the best possible way to have labelTexts change based on the text being put in a Text Field?

Tags: flutter

I am working on making some label texts for Text Fields respond to if certain text fields have text in them. Example being if fields B and C are blank, the labelText for field A will have an asterisk before it ("* Label"). Or if field A is blank the labelText for B and C will have an asterisk before it ("* Label"). I have it sort of working currently, but to have the correct asterisk appear after I type in a field I have to swipe the drawer away Im doing this in and reopen it. Kinda like setting the state so it knows that theres new stuff to display. How would I get it to change the correct label right when I type instead of having to do it manually? Thanks!

Field A

```
                           TextField(
                              controller: Data.NumberEditingController,
                              obscureText: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  ),
                                  labelText: requiredNumber(),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(105, 105, 105, 10),
                                  )),
                            ),
```

Field B

```
                           TextField(
                              controller: Data.NameEditingController,
                              obscureText: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  ),
                                  labelText: requiredName(),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(105, 105, 105, 10),
                                  )),
                            ),
```

Field C

```
TextField(
                              controller: Data.addressEditingController,
                              obscureText: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  ),
                                  labelText: requiredAddress(),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(105, 105, 105, 10),
                                  )),
                            ),
```

These are the functions I use to check for any text in the controllers so they can return the correct label to use. As stated above they work correctly but only upon dismissing the drawer and opening it again so everything is refreshed and I want it to be automatic

```
  requiredNumber() {
    if (Data.addressEditingController.text == "") {
      return "* Number";
    }
    else if (Data.nameEditingController.text == "") {
      return "* Number";
    }
    else {
      return "Number";

    }
  }

  requiredName() {
    if (Data.numberEditingController.text == "") {
      return "* Name";
    }
    else {
      return "Name";
    }
  }

  requiredAddress() {
    if (Data.numberEditingController.text == "") {
      return "* Address";
    }
    else {
      return "Address";
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have all the right logic in place, you just need to implement a reactive solution that triggers re-builds automatically. Several ways to do this, check out this post about managing textfields with GetX. Really easy to accomplish what you want to do if you implement this solution. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727181/assign-value-of-texteditingcontroller-inside-buildmethod/66727643#66727643

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution and cleanest for your case would be to put the logic inside the `onChanged` property of the TextField. I'll give an example using your first function:

Change this:

```
 requiredName() {
    if (Data.numberEditingController.text == "") {
      return "* Name";
    }
    else {
      return "Name";
    }
  }
```

into this:

```
String requiredNumber = "Number";
String requiredName = "Name";
String Address = "Address";

//and inside your TextField for the Number for example, use onChanged

 onChanged: (value) {
                if (value == '') {
                  setState(() {
                    requiredName = '* Name';
                  });
                } else {
                   setState(() {
                    requiredName = 'Name';
                  });
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

- define String variables for all your labels in your stateful widget:

```dart
    String numberLabel = '';
```

- Add listeners on all your textControllers during initState like so:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Start listening to changes.
    addressEditingController.addListener(setState((){numberLabel=requiredNumber()})); // Im not sure here callback may be wrapped in () {}
  }
```

- Then use this variables in your `labelText` properties:

```dart
     labelText: numberLabel,
```

- Remove registered listeners before `dispose` method:

```dart
 @override
  void dispose() {
    addressEditingController.removeListener(setState((){numberLabel=requiredNumber()}));
    addressEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```