# error: The non-nullable local variable 'newTaskTitle' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone the first error is in the title , let me  show the code first :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todoye_app_angela/models/task_data.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.limeAccent[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
            topRight: Radius.circular(60),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.brown[900]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (newText) {
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
              autocorrect: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.brown[800]!,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                ),
                hintText: 'Type Your Task ...',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green[900],
                ),
                helperStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.brown[900],
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.brown[900]!,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                    .addTask(newTaskTitle);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown[900]),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                    (states) => Colors.lightGreen),
                elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => 6),
                shadowColor:
                    MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.green),
                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                    (states) => Size.square(40.67)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error is in the onPress elevated button where i am trying to add this value to "addTask" method ...i have fixed this errro by the change below :

```
String? newTaskTitle;
```

Now I get this new error :
error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
it points to this method :

```
void addTask(String newTaskTitle) {
    _tasks.add(Task(name: newTaskTitle));
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

i have also fixed it by changing it to this one :

```
void addTask(String? newTaskTitle) {
    _tasks.add(Task(name: newTaskTitle));
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Now I get this new error :
error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
which points to this code :

```
class Task {
  final String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({
    required this.name,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  void toggleDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

which i have also fixed it and here is the change :

```
class Task {
  final String? name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({
    required this.name,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  void toggleDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

and now this error again :
error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. it seems like this error loves me !?...
which point to this code {this is the whole file }:

```
class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // the consumer widget comes from the provider package we simply wrap it around the widget we want to listen to ....we have to specify the data type we want to have access to then...
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      // then we provide the builder property which takes 3 arguments => 1: context : where we are in the widget tree ? second: it will provide the current data [Provider.of<TaskData>(context).task] and we can give that object a name ..here we named it taskData and at last it takes a property called child.
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        // here we return any widget that is needed to built based on this taskData .
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TaskTile(
              taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,
              isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,
              checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
                // setState(() {
                //   Provider.of<TaskData>(context).tasks[index].toggleDone();
                // });
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

it points to this line :

```
taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,
```

which gets me to this file :

```
class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String taskTitle;
  final bool isChecked;
  final ValueChanged<bool?> checkboxCallback;

  const TaskTile({
    required this.taskTitle,
    required this.isChecked,
    required this.checkboxCallback,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        taskTitle,
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.lime,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: checkboxCallback,
        // onChanged: toggleCheckBoxState,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this file wants me to change this code :

```
final String taskTitle;
```

to this one :

```
final String? taskTitle;
```

and at last this code :

```
title: Text(
        taskTitle,
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),
      ),
```

to this one :

```
title: Text(
        taskTitle!,
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),
      ),
```

then i hotrestared the app and tried to add a new task to list but i get this error :
Null check operator used on a null value
and it point to this part of this code :

```
title: Text(
            taskTitle!,
            style: TextStyle(
              decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
            ),
          ),
```

Null Safety in dart is really confusing ..it makes a loop of confusion that doesn't let the programmer write code in peace ....
please help me solve this problem ...
I really appreciate it in advance.

Comment: "it makes a loop of confusion that doesn't let the programmer write code in peace" ... You can break the look by just *checking for `null`*.  For example: `onPressed: () { if (newTaskTitle != null) { Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).addTask(newTaskTitle); } }`.

Comment: i have tried it before and it doesnt work .the problem is in the error : error: The non-nullable local variable 'newTaskTitle' must be assigned before it can be used. how to solve this problem ?

Comment: No, since your variable is conditionally initialized, you need to make it nullable and add null-checks. It doesn't make sense to check if a non-nullable variable is null. Alternatively make it non-nullable but initialize it with a default, non-null value.

Comment: Its 2023 and the problem statement still exists after nearly completing the Flutter course by Angela Wu!

Answer (score 14):

just add `late`  keyword before newTaskTitle declaration. as follows.

```
late String newTaskTitle;
```

this error is because dart null safety where you cannot asign null type to non-nullable fields.

Comment: i have done your suggestion but i get this error : LateInitializationError: Local 'newTaskTitle' has not been initialized. how to solve this one ?

Comment: another poin is i have tried to agive it an initial value like an empty String ''; but in the app when I type the the new task and add the to the list it doesnt give me the updated value it show nothing on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
String? newTaskTitle;
```

use this

```
final newTaskTitle = TextEditingController();
```

and on the `TextField` change the on change to

```
controller:newTaskTitle,
```

then on the `onPressed` change to this

```
onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                    .addTask(newTaskTitle.text);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
```

this is the right way to change string in StatelessWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a null check(!) in newtasktitle and it will work

like in my code I added here

```
onPressed: (){
  Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).addTask**(newTaskTitle!);**
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do 2 things:

First

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String? newTaskTitle;
```

Second

```
onPressed: () {
                    Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                        .addTask(newTaskTitle!);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
```

Make sure you **add listen: false** as the nullcheck (!) will not be enough

Answer (score 0):

1.i turn my AddTaskScreen into statfulWidget.

2.than i put newtaskname above widget build method : String
newTaskName;

3.i added setState in onchange of the textfield.

it works ,i dont why

Answer (score 0):

2023 and I encountered the issue.. Posting The fix that worked for me for others who might come here:

1. Read Why stateless along with controller should not be used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981098/2046382
2. Make the "AddTaskScreen" widget Stateful
3. Move the String newTaskTitle; outside the build method. And make it 'late'.

> ```
>  class AddTaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
>   static const String id = "add_task_screen";
>
>   @override
>   State<AddTaskScreen> createState() => _AddTaskScreenState();
> }
>
> class _AddTaskScreenState extends State<AddTaskScreen> {
>   late String newTaskTitle;
>    ..... Rest of the code
> ```