# Empty controllers in simple login form

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following code, I'm trying to make a login screen. However, even after I type email and password, I get a popup telling me "Email or password is empty", which is expected inside my if check.

login_page.dart

```
import 'package:chat_app/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/components/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/components/custom_textfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function()? onTap;

  LoginPage({super.key, required this.onTap});

  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void login(BuildContext context) async {
    final authService = AuthService();
    final localContext = context;

    String email = _emailController.text.trim();
    String password = _passwordController.text.trim();

    if (email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: localContext,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Error"),
          content: const Text("Email or password is empty"),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(localContext),
              child: const Text("Ok"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
      return; // Exit the method if email or password is empty
    }

    try {
      await authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          _emailController.text.trim(), _passwordController.text.trim());
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog(
        context: localContext,
        builder: (localContext) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Error"),
          content: Text(e.toString()),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(localContext),
              child: const Text("Ok"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.message_rounded,
            size: 60,
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 60),
          Text(
            "Welcome back, you've been missed",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          CustomTextField(
            hintText: "caio@exorcise.com",
            obscureText: false,
            controller: _emailController,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 25),
          CustomTextField(
            hintText: "Password",
            obscureText: true,
            controller: _passwordController,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 25),
          CustomButton(text: "Login", onTap: () => login(context)),
          const SizedBox(height: 25),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Not a member? ",
                style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: onTap,
                child: Text(
                  "Register now",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

custom_textfield.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  CustomTextField({super.key, required controller, required this.hintText, required this.obscureText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: obscureText,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          filled: true,
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just can't understand how the controllers are appearing as an empty string like "", as if they aren't receiving values at all. Any sugestions?

Comment: Can you include the code for `CustomTextField`?

Comment: Also please note that you should use `TextEditingController` in a `StatefulWidget`, so you can control its lifecycle and dispose when the state is disposed. See [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981098/13625293)

Comment: Added the text field code! And also changed the login widget to stateful, does it help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `CustomTextField`, you have a `controller` field that is initialized with a `TextEditingController()`, while the `controller` parameter from the constructor is not used. It makes `CustomTextField` uses its own `TextEditingController` instead of using the one passed from the parent widget. Fix it by applying these two changes:

```dart
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;
  final TextEditingController controller; // (1) Remove the assignment

  // (2) Change `required controller` to `required this.controller`
  CustomTextField({super.key, required this.controller, required this.hintText, required this.obscureText});
```

Comment: Spot on! You have no idea of how many time I slept on this hahah, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Just change the `onTap`
Instead of this

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: onTap,
                child: Text(
                  "Register now",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

To This

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: ()=>onTap(),
                    child: Text(
                      "Register now",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: That has no change, I've tried it too... The button calls the function as expected, just the controllers are empty